# Marshalling 0/False in a nested struct to json whilst using omitempty

Tags: json, go, struct

When marshalling a struct to JSON I am able to assign a variable to it's corresponding "empty value" and still pass it even when using omitempty, however I am unable to achieve the same result in a nested struct as it get's omitted despite being a pointer. Is this possible?

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar Bar `json:"bar,omitempty"`
    A *int  `json:"a,omitempty"`  //Does not get omitted when a = 0
    B *bool `json:"b,omitempty"`  //Does not get omitted when b = false
}

type Bar struct {
    X *int  `json:"x,omitempty"`  //Gets omitted when x = 0
    Y *bool `json:"y,omitempty"` //Gets omitted when y = false
}
```

Comment: Nothing here will be serialized, because none of the fields are exported. Please make a complete example of what you're seeing. If you export all the fields, this works as intended.

Comment: Sorry, the fields are exported. Basically the values of X and Y within bar when set to 0/false respectively are omitted when I marshal Foo. However A and B in Foo are not omitted when they are set to 0/false respectively

Comment: @j0ykls1cCMbTWfD1: please show a complete example of what happens, and what you expect to happen. This works as expected: https://play.golang.org/p/850qkyLYKU

Comment: create Bar as a pointer to Bar

Answer (score 1):

Thats because they aren't empty.. You are setting them to 0/false. 0/false doesn't mean that they aren't there, you've given then a space in memory by assigning them a value.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {
    Bar Bar   `json:"bar,omitempty"`
    A   *int  `json:"a,omitempty"` //Does not get omitted when a = 0
    B   *bool `json:"b,omitempty"` //Does not get omitted when b = false
}

type Bar struct {
    X *int  `json:"x,omitempty"` //Gets omitted when x = 0
    Y *bool `json:"y,omitempty"` //Gets omitted when y = false
}

func main() {
    var obj Foo
    a := 0 // a will not be not empty, it's set to 0
    obj.A = &a

    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(obj, "", " ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))

    var obj2 Foo
    // a and everything else will be empty, nothing is set

    b, _ = json.MarshalIndent(obj2, "", " ")
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

`The "omitempty" option specifies that the field should be omitted from the encoding if the field has an empty value, defined as false, 0, a nil pointer, a nil interface value, and any empty array, slice, map, or string.`

The wording could be better, but empty in this case means that nothing has been assigned to that field. It doesn't mean if the field is literally set to 0 or false it will be empty.  False and 0 are values as well and if you assign them then the field becomes 0 or false.